# Python - Using a dictionary to check query and retrieve an answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So, as per a section of my code:

```
ValidInputs = ['wet', 'water', 'liquid', 'mobile', 'iphone']
root = Tk()
def iphone():
   while True:
     Problem = input('State your problem')
     ProblemSplit = Problem.split(' ')
     if any(Words in ValidInputs for Words in ProblemSplit):
        print('Put your phone in the fridge for about 30 minutes, it will remove the moisture inside of your phone')
        time.sleep(2)
```

This works, but inefficiently I believe. As you can tell for example, if I used the input to the Problem variable, and inputted 'my phone is wet', it's going to detect that wet is indeed in the list ValidInputs, but then it is going to print the same answer/solution every time. So if I added more acceptable entries to the ValidInputs list, I don't want it to always print the same 'put your phone in the fridge', etcetera.

*So, how would I go about creating a dictionary with the format, 
Query:Solution
So that if any words from problem split are in Query, print solution.
Any suggestions?*

I've been having a go at this for around an hour now with no luck, I've been close but yet so far if you get what I mean, with my own research, but it's becoming tiresome, so,

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about you tell us what your code is supposed to do via example?

Comment: I wish I could by example, but it's not finished, nor working properly yet, but basically, it's a troubleshooting program which opens  GUI asking a user which model of mobile phone they have, as of now they can choose iphone, although there is a button for android, but i have done nothing with it yet, and they enter their problem and it checks the problem for possible matches to a solution ( the question i am asking), but if no solution can be found, a file is created which is supposedly sent to a technician ( fake technician lol), it's just for a project i was given

Comment: Does that answer what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a minimal example of what I believe you are looking for.

```
solutions = {'wet' : 'put into microwave', 'ring' : 'hit with hammer', 'battery' : 'more jiggawatts'}

def find_solution():
    problems = input('State your problem: ').lower().split(' ')
    for problem in set(problems):
        if problem in solutions:
            print(solutions[problem])

while True:
    find_solution()
```

Comment: You are a living legend, thank you, works perfectly, and makes the splitting more efficient, oh and the jiggawatts part got me :D